# Make the card view in bootstrap with icon 3d

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to achieve this using Bootstrap 4 and some custom CSS style

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-around">
                        <div class="card-icon">
                            <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-category">
                            <p>Used Space</p>
                            <h3>49/50</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body ">

                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                        2 days ago
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am unable to get this result I am new to CSS and Bootstrap.

Comment: I'm also interested, but using Bootstrap 5. Did you find a solution for this @Benjamin ?